# Assessing fraud risk with apple

Tags: ios, jwt

Apple provides a means to get metrics related to fraudulent applications.
See: [Assessing Fraud Risk](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/assessing_fraud_risk)

We are having trouble getting a successful response.

We are getting HTTP 401 response code.
That points to JWT not being created correctly. Has anyone else seen this or can point to how they did it successfully?

Here's what we have done.

1. We obtain a attestation value (that we trust--and we are working on validating it as well--in case this is the issue).
2. We decode attestation using CBOR ([Apple validating apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/validating_apps_that_connect_to_your_server) and extract the value of the `receipt` field. We used the python library cbor2 (basically just base64 decode raw value and then call `cbor2.loads(<base 64 decoded value>)`
3. We create a JWT token to use in the metric request via:

```
# adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002949/how-to-create-a-json-web-token-jwt-using-openssl-shell-commands

# Construct the header
jwt_header=$(echo -n '{"alg":"ES256","kid":"SECRET"}' | base64 | sed s/\+/-/g | sed 's/\//_/g' | sed -E s/=+$//)


NOW=$(date +"%s")

# Construct the payload
payload=$(echo -n "{\"iss\":\"SECRET\", \"iat\": $NOW}" | base64 | sed s/\+/-/g |sed 's/\//_/g' |  sed -E s/=+$//)


PRIVATE_KEY_BASE64_ONE_LINE="SECRET"

hexsecret=$(echo -n ${PRIVATE_KEY_BASE64_ONE_LINE} | base64 --decode | xxd -p)


# Calculate hmac signature -- note option to pass in the key as hex bytes
hmac_signature=$(echo -n "${jwt_header}.${payload}" |  openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:$hexsecret -binary | base64  | sed s/\+/-/g | sed 's/\//_/g' | sed -E s/=+$//)

# Create the full token
jwt="${jwt_header}.${payload}.${hmac_signature}"

echo "$jwt"
```

4. Send request as described in apple's doc. Note that we use "Bearer" as prefix as described in [Generating tokens](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns):

```
curl -i --verbose -H "Authorization: bearer <JWT>" \
       -X POST --data-binary @receipt.bin \
       https://data-development.appattest.apple.com/v1/attestationData
```